# How to handle error in Vuejs with proper way?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new to Vuejs, my building project is working on car, using Laravel back-end and Vuejs for front-end. Currently, there are 2 cases considering as Not_Found_Exception (HTTP = 404) when submit car registration number to API.

One is: There is no record in backend system. In this case, API will response this message "Vehile not found".

Another one: There is record in backend system for this car registration number but there is no data in other relationship tables (such as: data for engine type, data for transmission type, etc). In this case, API will response this message "There is no data for this vehicle".

On the frontend, I need to show error message reponsed from API depends on specific case (2 above messages), but previous developer are using hard-code for showing message on front-end, it is always "Vehicle registration not found".

The js code like below:

```
async searchVehicleRego() {
  try {
    const { data } = await useFetchForApi('/search-vehicles/rego', params: {rego: ABCXYZ})
  } catch (error) {
    this.handleErrorVehicleRego(error)
  }
}

handleErrorVehicleRego(error) {
  // I am wondering if this behaviour is proper to handle error when using http status code from api      to set value for error, I have no experience with this, any explaination or instruction is totally welcome.
  // console.log(error) . Output is below:
  vehicle_registration: Vehicle not found  -> This is error message responsed from API

  if (error.status === 404) {
    this.errors = error.errors
    this.ifRegoNotFound = true
  } else if (error.status === 422) {
    this.errors = abcxyz
  }
}
```

This is the template code `FindYourCarForm.vue`

```
<div v-if="!isRegoNotFound">
  <p>
    Don't remember your registration number? // If don't remember registration number, use below link to manual select, when click this link, new form will open with manufacturer and model for select
    <Link text="Manual select" />
  </p>
</div>
<div v-else>
  <Button>
    <span>
      Vehicle registration not found. // If registration number is not found, this text is hard code. I want to replace this by dynamic error returned from API.
      <span>Manual select</span>
    </span>
  </Button>
</div>

<script setup>
  const hasError = computed(() =>
    sellMyCarForm.hasErrors ? Object.values(sellMyCarForm.hasErrors) : 
    false
  )
</script>
```

Code in `store/sell-my-car.js`

```
getters: {
  hasErrors: (state) => state.errors,
}
```

My question is how can I display specific error from API at the hard code text?
Any help is very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: so you can added a message under your if conditions `this.errorMessage = 'Error message.';` and put this error var above `<span>Manual select</span>` like `{{ errorMessage }}`

Comment: refer this https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#text-interpolation

Comment: @Adi Thanks for your instruction. How about the code in handleErrorVehicleRego function, set error value by api status code response, is it a proper way?

Comment: can you `console.log(error)` at beginning in `handleErrorVehicleRego(error)` function? Then i might be able to give more insight and let's worry about restructuring it later, did your issue resolve?

Comment: @Adi Yes, I can, it is error returned from api. It could display error depends on the specific case. But when I click submit button, error text disappears because in `searchVehicleRego` , first line is `this.clearErrors()` which is function used to clear error on state.

Comment: @Adi but above `<span>Manual select</span>`, I used `{{ hasError[0] }}` to display error, `hasError` is computed function to get error from state. Code like this `hasErrors: (state) => state.errors,`. That's why when click submit button, meaning that call to `searchVehicleRego`, the error disappears. That is what I am not epxecting.

Comment: Sorry i meant post your console.log in your question, just edit the question and add `Edit:` at the bottom. Also, `hasError` where is the var declared?

Comment: @Adi I edit my question with more information, and include `console.log(error)` as well.